# Can't drop a Date column KeyError: "['Date'] not found in axis

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe that has date, sales, and budget as column names. I want to drop the date column but it gives me an error `KeyError: "['Date'] not found in axis"`

Below is my code:

```
df2 = df.copy()   # make a copy of the dataframe object
df2.drop(columns = ['Date'], inplace=True)   # drop the Date columns
```

The Datatype of all columns

```
Date                           datetime64[ns]
Sales                                 float64
Budget                                float64
PPV                                   float64
SOPPV                                 float64
dtype: object
```

The full Trackback:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-22d4dafeb1cb> in <module>
----> 1 df2 = df.drop(columns = ['Date'], inplace=True)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3995             level=level,
   3996             inplace=inplace,
-> 3997             errors=errors,
   3998         )
   3999 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3934         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   3935             if labels is not None:
-> 3936                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
   3937 
   3938         if inplace:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
   3968                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
   3969             else:
-> 3970                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   3971             result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   3972 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   5016         if mask.any():
   5017             if errors != "ignore":
-> 5018                 raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
   5019             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   5020         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: "['Date'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: Can you share some of your data? Are you sure you don't have any spaces after or before `Date`? Can you perhaps print `df2.columns` for us?

Comment: @Grayrigel thank you for pointing that out. I'm too ignorant to assume that all column names are in perfect format. the Date column has an extra space at the end. The issue has been resolve.

Comment: It happens to all of us! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an additional space before/after the `Date`. So, either you can edit the column name manually or you can try:

```
df.drop(columns=['Date '],inplace=True)
```

Or

```
df.drop(columns=[' Date'],inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and eliminate all lines with nan `df2.dropna()` then you I think you can drop it? `df2.drop(['Date'])`

Comment: You don't need `axis=1` if you are specifying `columns`.

Comment: well, he could just try and put just 1 param on the code.